# Emacs lisp; how to make a string from a variable of any type?

Tags: elisp

Like error messages for wrongly called functions show, eg.:

```
(message (file-attributes "."))
```

Produces the message:

```
"eval: Wrong type argument: stringp, ("/home14/tjones" 1 0 0 (20415 35598) (20211 19255) (20211 19255) 14 "lrwxrwxrwx" t ...)"
```

How do you do this type of translation intentionally, eg.:

```
(message (thing-to-string (file-attributes ".")))
```

To message something like:

```
("/home14/tjones" 1 0 0 (20415 35598) (20211 19255) (20211 19255) 14 "lrwxrwxrwx" t ...)
```

This is for debugging/info only. I'm assuming there's a way as message is doing it, but is this exposed to us users?

Comment: This is Emacs. Pretty much everything as exposed, with exemplary built-in documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into `prin1-to-string` and related functions (`prin1`, `princ`, etc). And do try the manual! http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Functions.html

Comment: Agree that this is probably hard to find if you don't know it's there.

Answer (score 5):

The first argument to `message` is supposed to be a format string (same as the one you pass to the `format` function. If you give it the format "%s" (or "%S" as in [Stefan's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10766741/35881)) it will stringify anything you give it as the next argument.

The capital S version will escape characters in the string so that it can be read again as an s-expression. In this case, I think that is what you want. So, you don't need to change your code very much to get what you are looking for:

```
(message "%S" (file-attributes "."))
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example, `message` did not do anything (it just refused to run), so the translation to string was done by the read-eval-print loop which caught the error and turned it into a text message.
But yes, `message` can also do that, and it does that by calling `format`, which internally uses things like `prin1-to-string`.
So `(format "%S" <foo>)` would do your thing-to-string.