# Emacs Lisp wrong-type-argument in format-time-string

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I'm using org-mode and trying to set up a capture template to put a TODO under a heading named by the current date.  For example, for today (12/12/12), my heading would be:

```
*** Dec 12
```

So I have tried this in my template:

```
 '(org-capture-templates (quote
                          (
                           ;;; note: this template works
                           ("d" "Defect" entry (file+headline "~/doc/org/defects.org" "Open") "** TODO %^{Defect}")
                           ;;; this template does not
                           ("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/doc/org/timesheet.org"  (format-time-string "%h %e")) "**** TODO %i%?"))))
```

However, I get a `wrong-type-argument stringp` exception.  Here's a bit of the stacktrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp (format-time-string "%h %e"))
  regexp-quote((format-time-string "%h %e"))
  (format org-complex-heading-regexp-format (regexp-quote hd))
  (re-search-forward (format org-complex-heading-regexp-format (regexp-quote hd)) nil t)
  (if (re-search-forward (format org-complex-heading-regexp-format ...) nil t) (goto-char (point-at-bol)) (goto-char (point-max)) (or (bolp) (insert "\n")) (insert "* " hd "\n") (beginning-of-line 0))
 ... snip ...
```

I have a feeling it's more of a generic Emacs Lisp issue rather than an org-mode question but I'm not sure what it could be.  I ran across a post (I cannot find it again) that said something to the effect that by putting format-time-string into parenthesis, Lisp didn't see it as a string.  Which seems true enough because if I evaluate it, nothing is printed unless I do an insert.  But I don't want to insert it - I want the expression to be evaluated and used as a string.  [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755677/emacs-lisp-how-to-make-a-string-from-a-variable-of-any-type) has me thinking similarly, that I have to do something to get the formatted string to appear as a string.

Comment: something is really wrong with the definition of your template -- the part where you tried to put the function call to format-time-string is not being evaluated, but rather being treated as a string, but you gave it a list consisting of two objects, one being a symbol and the other being a string.  I don't know enough about org-mode templates to really help you any better at the moment though.

Comment: I think you're right about that symbol and string.  If I replace the (format-time-string "%h %e") expression with a simple string (e.g., "Dec 12"), it works.  If I evaluate the format-time-string by inserting into a buffer, it also returns "Dec 12".  But for some reason the template doesn't like to see it.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: that must be it then.  I guess the confusing part is that the way file+headline is put in the template it appears to be a function call so doing what you did by nesting yet another call in there might seem logical.  Org-mode already has some support for timestamps -- is any of it useful to you?

Comment: I don't think so, in this case.  What I'm doing with the file+headline  capture template is to file a TODO under a headline with an embedded date which is sort of my own custom process.  A more org-modey way to do it would involve the agenda but I don't think there's a way to use timestamps to file that new TODO where I want it.  Good thought, though.

Comment: Mmm... as you're quoting all the list, it seems that the function call to `format-time-string` is not evaluated. Also, `format-time-string` will yield only a value for each day, so it is a constant. You can try to substitute the quote by the quasi-quote and evaluate the expression with a comma. I'll put an answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is too much quoting and the call is never evaluated. As you said, a string works, so you could try to change that inside `quote` to a quasi-quote and a comma. Also, looking at the format, it seems that this variable is a list of lists, and you have a list of lists of lists. My guess is this:

```
`(org-capture-templates (
                         ("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/doc/org/timesheet.org" ,(format-time-string "%h %e")) "**** TODO %i%?")))
```

I'm not aware of the templating format, but you have to be sure the function call is evaluated to produce the actual list with the values evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Unfortunately, it doesn't like the comma: I get: "format: Wrong type argument: stringp, \,". This is actually a list of capture templates and the others work and fall within the quote. I should add that into the original question. Please take a look and see if it raises any new thoughts. Thanks!